# What's format of putting variable in the query string in JSP?

Tags: jsp, query-string

The question is like a link:

```
 <a href="http://www.sample.com/sample.jsp?name=nameVariable">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

what's the right format i should put on the above line if nameVariable is a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable comes from a parameter then `${param.nameVariable}`

```
<a href="http://www.sample.com/sample.jsp?name=${param.nameVariable}">Visit W3fools.com</a>
```

And if the variable is a plain JSP variable then `${nameVariable}`

```
<a href="http://www.sample.com/sample.jsp?name=${nameVariable}">Visit W3fools.com</a>
```